# Update all records unless value = 'abc'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace, sql-update

I need to update all records where telephone1 character length = 12 but dont update if ContactId = 'the values listed below in the code'

I think my logic is wrong..

```
Update Contact
SET Telephone1 = replace(Telephone1, '-', '')
where LEN(Telephone1) = 12
NO UPDATE if ContactId IN ('332C9C1F-B397-E211-97CB-00265585B80D', '860E5A58-4551-E311-BEC7-005056AF5FAD', 'D3EBAAAD-F8B7-E211-928F-005056AF5FAD', '6B4C76A2-5792-E211-97CB-00265585B80D', '4F4AB38B-353B-E311-BEC7-005056AF5FAD')
```

Any help/advise is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Update Contact
   SET Telephone1 = replace(Telephone1, '-', '')
 where LEN(Telephone1) = 12
   AND ContactId NOT IN ('332C9C1F-B397-E211-97CB-00265585B80D', 
                         '860E5A58-4551-E311-BEC7-005056AF5FAD', 
                         'D3EBAAAD-F8B7-E211-928F-005056AF5FAD', 
                         '6B4C76A2-5792-E211-97CB-00265585B80D', 
                         '4F4AB38B-353B-E311-BEC7-005056AF5FAD')
```

Comment: Worked great, So simple...I was close! urggggg. Thanks showing me!